# How to auto size chat bubble element based on text content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a demo chat application and I styled a chat bubble but I don't how to achieve the auto size bubble chat. Currently, it has a fixed width and height, and I want the bubble's size to fit the text content.

Here's a scaled down version of what I currently have:

```js
function typo() {
  var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var x = '<p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p>';
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;
}

var input = document.getElementById("myText");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("btn-chat").click();
  }
});
```

```css
.bubble{ 
  clear: both;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #C28584;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin : 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bubble:after{ 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px 30px 11px 0;
  border-color: transparent #C28584;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  left: -30px;
  top: 31px;
}

.bottom{ 
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
} 

.widebox{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

button {
 float : right;
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-right: -50px;
 margin-top : -28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
        <div class="btn-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="bottom">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input class="widebox" type="text" id="myText" value="">
    <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The demo is here, you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/mzdf0dbw/5/

Comment: Please use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show your code and its problems.

Comment: Get rid of your fixed width and height for the chat bubble. `Height` and `width` should be `auto`

Comment: I posted the demo in fiddle ..You can find it below my question. Thanks for the time and effort

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the auto size chat bubble just using html ,css and javascript alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and achieved it. Please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrathod101/65ta4kxo/1/) and let me know if this is what desired output is.

```
<html>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .bubble {
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #C28584;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-left: 15px;
    /* min-width: 50px; */
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

  .bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 32px 11px 0;
    border-color: transparent #C28584;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    left: -30px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 01px;
  }

  .widebox {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }

  button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-top: -28px;
  }

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
          <div class="btn-group">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="bottom">
      <div id="demo"></div>
      <input class="widebox" type="text" id="myText" value="">
      <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function typo() {
      var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
      var x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</div></p>';
      document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
      var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;
    }

    var input = document.getElementById("myText");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("btn-chat").click();
      }
    });

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: yeaah ! thanks a lot Mr.Yogesh for taking your time and effort to solve this for me

Comment: Welcome. You can now accept this answer, so that other people with the same question in the future will know this is the correct answer

Comment: yeaah sure Sir ! i tried to add a scroll bar using Javascript but i couldn't do it ,so that the previous texts can be scrolled to look at them again,

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, change `height: 75px;` to `height:auto;`

Comment: Sir i did ! but its still not responsive yet :( is it possible to make it (chat bubble) look like the chat applications which we use on mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://leaverou.github.io/bubbly/) (bubbly) shows an example of how to achieve the chat bubble using CSS.  If you want to experiment with CSS border radius values to get the right bubble "look", try [CSS Borders website](http://cssborders.com).

Comment: But that site doesn't cover how to auto size bubble chat according to our text chat..Thanks i figured it out now am trying to add scroll bar to the chat.